# ImportError: cannot import name 'Lock' from 'threading'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to import numpy into my Python code and am getting this error:

```
File "C:\python-venv\ENV\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
from threading import Lock
ImportError: cannot import name 'Lock' from 'threading' (c:\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py)
```

Does anyone know the reason for this error and how to solve?

Comment: Please either edit your question (and use English), or move it to https://pt.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: You have a file called `token.py` in your working directory. Remove it, rename it, or change to another directory.

Comment: it's working, thanks!!